# htaccess rewrite resulting in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to get pretty urls using htaccess for SLIR image resizing plugin.

I want to rewrite something like below:

**Before Rewrite:**
localhost/img/600x400/slider/image.jpg

**After Rewrite**
localhost/application/public/slir/index.php?r=slir&w=600&h=400&i=img/slider/image.jpg

But the following code is returning a 500 Internal server error...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4})/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png) application/public/slir/index.php?r=slir&w=$2&h=$3&i=$1/$4.$5 [NC,NE,QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Please help me.....

---

## **UPDATE**

I thought it was a File Permissions issue...
so I checked all the related directories and files, surprisingly there were all 755/644.
Then I directly checked the **/application/public/slir/index.php**. It was not accessible.

I created another file named **hello.php** in the same slir directory and **hello.php** was accessible.
Then I moved the SLIR directory to the another folder named **public**. Here, both the **index.php** and **hello.php** were accessible.

After that, I moved SLIR directory to back to the original **scripts** folder. In **scripts** folder, **hello.php** is accessible but **index.php** is not accessible.
Now, Both files have same permissions and are in same folder.. I dont know what is happening here... :/ :/

**Someone please help me......**

Comment: What happens if you just try to open localhost/application/public/slir/index.php?r=slir&w=600&h=400&i=img/slider/image.jpg
 do you still get 500? If so you probably have some simple permissions issue where files are not 644/755.

Comment: when I am using it on localhost then it works fine...But when I upload my website to **subdomain.example.com** then it again gives the 500 Internal Error...What is the problem I can't understand.. :(

Comment: @IRISIndigo I have updated the question. Please read the update in the original post...

Comment: added new answer - the right one...

Comment: If you get an Error 500, please tell us what is in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is looking at this - the problem I found was these two lines in the htaccess file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file none
```

&

```
php_value auto_append_file none
```

some servers don't allow them.

moving them to my `php.ini` file solved it for me:

```
auto-prepend-file = none

auto-append-file = none
```

Comment: For anyone else looking, this was the easiest, best answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because you are editing the .htaccess file with a Windows based editor like notepad. Notepad adds some characters to the file which you can't see, but they mess with the .htaccess. I recommend using an editor like Notepad++ and setting the mode to Unix, so it won't mess with the server..
Speaking technically that is because Linux and Windows have different type of EOL ( End Of Line ) so that notepad adds some characters to the end of every line to go to the next line, but Unix won't recognize them, because it has it's own type of EOL..

Comment: If this is the situation I think the problem lies more in the BOM (Byte Order Marker) that Notepad adds in the begining of the file than the fact that introduces CRLF linefeeds. Byte Order Marker are two bytes in the beginning of the file that Notepad will not show you.

Comment: Go to Edit and change EOL Conversion to Unix and see if your problem is solved or no?

Answer (score 0):

Slashes are normally forbidden in query strings, but you can enable them by setting
[AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive.

You may also want your rewrite rule to use percent encoding for slashes (that is %2F) so after rewrite:
`localhost/application/public/slir/index.php?r=slir&w=600&h=400&i=img%2Fslider%2Fimage.jpg`

See also [How do you configure apache php to accept slashes in query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462082/how-do-you-configure-apache-php-to-accept-slashes-in-query-strings)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I think my apache is already configured to accept slashes in query strings

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate, phrased very differently:

[Has anyone used Smart Image Resizer on subdomain sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761733/has-anyone-used-smart-image-resizer-on-subdomain-sites)

The problem is the subdomain...